# Avoid apache to match filename in uris

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a litle app written in php, using apache. I have wrote the following in my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

So, basically I want to handle all uris in my index.php file. It's working almost fine, my problem is when I try to match an uri and there is a `.php` file with that name, for example if I have an `api.php` file, then the uri `http://localhost/app-name/api` throws an `404 error`

So, how can I handle all uris with `index.php`? why isn't the directive `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]` working properly?

Comment: Likely just MultiViews.

Comment: apache has no idea what you are tyong to do, so of course something it can't find will result in a 404.  add "FallbackResource index.php" to your .htaccess so apache sends anything it cant  find to your index.php

Comment: That would replace the `RewriteRule` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your code and turning off `multiviews`. It by default looks for files with an extension with the same name as you put in.

```
Options -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Side note, I've never seen anyone who *actually* wanted to use this feature.